# How do I fire a message box with if else condition and timespan value?

Tags: c#, arrays, if-statement, timespan

I have this code

*start time is another DateTime.now

*timeSinceStart is an array of timeSpan

*i believe that the for loop is for me to be able to create and store many values for the timespan and update the listview items(see link below for the photo of the form)

*f.ToString() is default 60(its an integer)

*the MH column in the picture is counting upwards, for ex. 1 2 3 4 5 6 etc etc

```
private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        for (int w = 0; w < listView1.Items.Count; w++)
        {
            timeSinceStart[w] = DateTime.Now - startTime[w];
            listView1.Items[w].SubItems[6].Text = (timeSinceStart[w].TotalSeconds.ToString());
            if (f.ToString() == listView1.Items[w].SubItems[6].Text)
            { 
                MessageBox.Show("dedede");
            }
            else
            {
                label3.Text = timeSinceStart[w].TotalSeconds.ToString();
            }
        }
```

I really cant make the message box pop up and also, the timespan value has decimal values, does it have a connection why the if condition doesn't trigger?

I have tried converting timespan to datetime and use datetime and timespan in the if else condition, it also doesnt seem to work.

here is the picture as i was saying:

[image: here is the picture as i was saying.]

edit* 
I have another form that let the user to input an integer and a combobox that contains "Hour" of "Minute".

this is the code it contains:

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Indicate How Many Minutes/Hours.");
        }
        else
        {
            string desu = textBox1.Text;
            int temp = 0;
            if (int.TryParse(desu, out temp))
            {
                if (comboBox1.Text == "Hours")
                {
                    //hours to seconds
                    time = temp * 3600;
                    eta = desu + " Hours";
                    sot = temp;
                    this.Close();
                }
                else if (comboBox1.Text == "Minutes")
                {
                    //minutes to seconds
                    time = temp * 60;
                    eta = desu + " Minutes";
                    sot = temp;
                    this.Close();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid integer");
            }
        }
    }
```

And then i pass the value of "time" into the form mentioned above

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        ETA_Input frm = new ETA_Input(this);
        frm.ShowDialog();
        if (frm.time != 0)
        {
            string name = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            int deku = Int32.Parse(name);
            string constring = "server=localhost;database=dbhorizon;uid=root;password=1234";
            string Query = "update tblUserIdd set User_Available = 'Ongoing' where User_ID='" + deku + "' ";

            MySqlConnection conDatabase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
            MySqlCommand cmdDatabase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDatabase);
            MySqlDataReader myReader;

            conDatabase.Open();
            myReader = cmdDatabase.ExecuteReader();


            string id = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            string naem = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            string field = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();



            f = frm.time;




            if (stdex == 0)
            {
                startTime[stdex] = DateTime.Now;

                stdex++;
            }
            else if (stdex >= 1)
            {
                startTime[stdex] = DateTime.Now;
                stdex++;
            }


            secondss = string.Format("{0:t}", DateTime.Now);


            string[] row = { id, naem, field, secondss, frm.eta,custb, f.ToString()  };
            var listViewItem = new ListViewItem(row);
            listView1.Items.Add(listViewItem);

            dgvref();
        }

    }
```

here.

Comment: Maybe `listView1.Items[w].SubItems[6].Text` is not 60 (could have some spaces at the end). If you are going to compare ints, i would rather parse the string to int and not the other way around

Comment: *"the timespan value has decimal values, does it have a connection why the if condition doesn't trigger"* - more likely yes. Ever heard about *debugging*? Set breakpoint and see it for yourself.

Comment: Can you tell us whats the values of f.ToString() and listView1.Items[w].SubItems[6].Text are? Check it with debugger...

Comment: Comparing strings, basically, is not a good idea. If you're operating DateTime type, you should operate it, not strings

Comment: Just debug your code and see the values you're comparing.

Comment: f.ToString() contains the user's input (int) and then that form contains codes that converts the input into seconds. its working fine tho. ill edit it so i can show the code to you.

Comment: i have already edited the post. i also indicated where did i get the f.ToString();

Comment: I think it worked when I replaced this code 
if (f.ToString() == listView1.Items[w].SubItems[6].Text)
with this one
if (timeSinceStart[w].TotalSeconds >= f && timeSinceStart[w].TotalSeconds <= f + 1)